# Are there any events planned to celebrate Sputnik's 60th anniversary today?

Tags: launch, history, sputnik

April 12 has [Yuri's Night](https://yurisnight.net/) to commemorate Yuri Gagarin's first orbital flight by a human.

The [launch of Sputnik 1](http://l5development.com/i_resource/history/DayInHistory.php?d=1004), the first satellite humanity put into orbit, on 4 October 1957 at 10:58pm Moscow time is at least as important event, but I'm unaware of any organized events to commemorate the occasion.

In any case, Happy Sputnik Day!  (It’s a [national holiday](https://l5nation.com/supt/holidays.php) for those of us who are citizens of the #L5Nation, celebrate it appropriately!)

This is picture of the day # [4727](https://photobyfred.com/SlideShow.php/ID=20171004) on [PhotoByFred.com](https://PhotoByFred.com):

[image: Happy Sputnik Day! photo for 4 October 2017 at PhotoByFred.com]

Comment: I hear there was supposed to be a question about it on SpaceExploration SE @FKEinternet, keep an eye out for it.

Answer (score 4):

There were a few things that were done, namely:

1. A number of news articles.
2. [Events at planetariums](http://uwm.edu/planetarium/event/60-years-of-sputnik/)
3. [Events at the Smithsonian/ other museums](https://airandspace.si.edu/events/60th-anniversary-sputnik)

I'm sure there were other events too, but I can't find references. I can't find any in Russia itself, interestingly enough.